# Issuing Ruby on Rails commands without the command line in Windows (Instant Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line

I'm working on a public computer where access to the cmd is restricted, i.e., I cannot access it at all.

How do issue commands such as "rails", "rake", or even install gems among other options I'd normally use the command line for with the cmd?

Comment: Way too many unknowns in your question, too... what OS?  No one knows the exact setup of this computer either - there's likely to be other things that are restricted - so "write a shell script / batch file and execute it from a file browser", "try to execute the commands through a programmer's editor such as SciTE", may or may not work.

Comment: In the heading I stated "Windows"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to run these commands...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Netbeans Ide to run the commands and install the gems. If you click on the project folder and press the third option(check the link), you will be able see a command window and you will see all the rake commands or you can give your own rake command there.

check the image in the given link

http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4036/4621723790_d608a67f68_o.jpg